Datetime Grouping
I will be grateful if i can get help with this SQL syntax. I have the table below. I want to sum both the localAmount_Dr and localAmount_Cr column, subtract the localAmount_Cr from the localAmount_Dr sum total to get a new column called Balance. I want to also group them by Y/M.

My SQL Syntax is as follows
select
date_format(CBDate, '%Y-%M')
sum(localAmount_Dr) as total_donation, 
sum(localAmount_Cr) as total_disbursement, 
(sum(localAmount_Dr) - sum(localAmount_Cr)) as balance  
from ccfdb.ccf_gencashbook  
where month(CBDate) = 04
group by CBDate, localAmount_Dr, localAmount_Cr;

The above syntax gives me the following results which i am not expecting.

What i want to achieve is that i want all the four columns with the first column being a single liner date followed by the rest of the columns as shown in the diagram below which is not the exact result i want (i meant the table below is not the exact result i want although is similar).

My challenge is how to modify the above SQL Syntax to make it add a one liner grouped date (ie 2024-April) as the first column.
I will be grateful if my syntax can be modified to give me the desired results. Thanks

GROUP BY date_format(CBDate, '%Y-%M')

@Akina, i have tried your solution before but i get the result as the second diagram

Need a self-join as well.

Please for further questions use text for the data example as following.
Data example
CREATE TABLE `ccf_gencashbook` (
  `CBDate` timestamp,
  `localAmount_Dr` int,
  `localAmount_Cr` int
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

insert into ccf_gencashbook values  
('2024-04-22 06:02:00',1500,0),
('2024-04-22 06:02:00',1200,0),
('2024-04-22 06:02:00',0,350),
('2024-04-22 06:02:00',0,200),
('2024-05-02 06:02:00',0,140),
('2024-05-02 06:02:00',0,250),
('2024-05-02 06:02:00',0,230),
('2024-05-02 06:02:00',0,400),
('2024-05-03 06:02:00',0,100);

Query
SELECT date_format(CBDate, '%Y-%M') as dt,
       SUM(localAmount_Dr) as total_donation,
       SUM(localAmount_Cr) as total_disbursement,
       SUM(localAmount_Dr) - SUM(localAmount_Cr) as balance
FROM ccf_gencashbook
GROUP BY dt;

Result
    dt      total_donation  total_disbursement  balance
2024-April     2700             550              2150
2024-May        0               1120            -1120

Add the where condition to filter the data as per your requirements.

Note. where month(CBDate) = 04 wont use an index if present on CBDate column. Better use WHERE CBDate >='2024-04-01 00:00:00' AND CBDate < '2024-05-01 00:00:00'
See example

@Basha thanks. It worked. Thank you
